# How to get keyword statistics using PHP/MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, statistics, keyword

I am Looking for a way to display ranking/statistics of Tag/Keywords. I tried but no success. I know PHP very well but I am confused about how to get statistics of a keyword using PHP/MYSQL.

Like this: http://bit.ly/gHLXXo (aka http://www.torrentpond.com/stats/keywords).

Please Solve my Problem.

EDIT: I just create a keywords table.. with (ID, Keywords, time, view) column and use some query to get result.. but no luck.. I don't know how to manage it.. Do I need to add 30 columns for each day or do I need to use serialize to store database as array? Is there any solution please give me ...

EDIT2: I don't need a chart or graph for this; I just need the keyword trends.

Comment: What have you tried? Any code? What is the structure of you data tables? How do you save your tags and manage the times its used etc.? - More information please!

Comment: Question edited.. Please read.. Thanks..

Comment: 'Please solve my problem' tends to get a pointer to [How to Ask Questions the Smart Way](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html).

Comment: `(ID, Keywords, time, view)` == (unique id, tagname, creation-time, times-used) ?? Or is keywords a list? What do you mean by `view`?

Answer (score 0):

You need sql query like this:

```
SELECT COUNT( * ) AS  `Rows` ,  `keyword_id` 
FROM  `keywords_table` 
GROUP BY  `keyword_id` 
ORDER BY  `Rows` DESC 
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Where "Rows" = count of this keyword and "keyword-id"  = keyword id or name.

This return you top 30 keywords with the number of times the keyword appears.

Comment: I'm not quite sure if this is true. Actually I suppose you get the first 30 keywords not matter what. I'm not sure that these are sorted by use-count.

Comment: @Smamatti I'm sure. Just try it before comment.

Comment: How can you be sure if you don't know the **exact** table structure of his database? The given structure `(ID, Keywords, time, view)` has room for interpretation. Don't think just because a structure seems logical everyone will use the version which is _good practice_. He **might** even create a single row for each time a tag has been used. How could you know?

Comment: @Smamatti you're right. But your first comment was about my SQL query.  I'm mean that my query really get **top** 30 keywords and not **just first** 30 keywords. In fact, I'm just write a example code, which he rewrite for their own purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Your first step should to consider what data is needed to allow the statistics to be generated.

You will need to keep track of the individual keywords (or sets of keywords).  Then, for each time one of the keywords is used, you'll insert a record into a statistical table which identifies the keyword and the date/time when it was used.  When the search keyword is new, you create a new keyword entry in the list of keywords, as well as an entry in the 'use of keywords' table.

Your aggregate processing then needs to compute how often each keyword was used in the relevant period.  You can do this daily; you won't be retrospectively adding new records.  Given the aggregated data stored over time, you can compute positions (rankings) and changes in position.  You can aggregate over days, weeks, months if need so be.  The aggregate data will be stored in separate tables from the operational data.  Once the basic unit of time (probably the day, maybe an hour) is past, you can consider whether to remove the original raw data - after you've done the first step aggregations.